# Как загрузиться с iso?

Tags: grub, boot, iso-образ

В связи с так и не решённой проблемой из моего предыдущего вопроса, я решил попробовать позапускать LiveCD других дистрибутивов и потестировать их. Но дисковода у меня нет, флешки тоже свободной нет. Я нашёл в Интернете, что grub умеет загружать iso образы. Делал всё по инструкции, но при попытке загрузиться ничего происходит, пункт на нажатия Enter не реагирует. Пробовал загружать виндовым загрузчиком, настраивая через EasyBCD, но дело доходит до initramfs и вываливается в консоль.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте как написано здесь: http://web.archive.org/web/20120106064925/https://zenway.ru/page/grub-2-booting-from-iso-img

Answer (score 1):

Хороший список параметров для загрузки разных операционных систем из .iso:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive