# Как установить AltLinux 7.0.5 из .iso при помощи GRUB2?

Tags: linux, grub, iso-образ, altlinux

Что надо написать в конфиг grub2, чтобы загрузился дистрибутив AltLinux 7.0.5 ?

Понятно, что нужно указать loop для grub.

```
menuentry "AltLinux 7.0.5"{
        insmod loopback
#       search --set --fs-uuid b316cbc2-4695-480c-b9b9-a555350d458a
        set isofile=/iso/altlinux-7.0.5-school-master-x86_64-ru-install-dvd5.iso
        loopback loop (${root})${isofile}
        linux (loop)/syslinux/alt0/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename=$isofile
        initrd (loop)/syslinux/alt0/full.cz
}
```

Непонятно, какие параметры передавать в строке параметров ядра,
так как для этого надо знать, как собирался full.cz (=initrd от altlinux) и какие параметры он понимает.

Такая загрузка совершенно точно возможна в [Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/casper.7.html), в [Debian](http://grml.org/online-docs/live-initramfs.en.7.html) и в [Fedora](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184695/where-isoboot-boot-isolinux-iso-scan-filename-parameters-are-documented).

вот такой же вопрос, только он там не отвечен:
https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/linux-install/5934581
вот этот вопрос в виде обобщенном для любых дистрибутивов:
[Как загрузиться с iso?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/344125/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-iso)
(отвечен на примере Ubuntu)

Этот вопрос социально значимый и глобального масштаба, так как флешки - это дополнительные материальные расходы, а возможность устанавливать без них увеличивает степень проникновения Linux в бедных регионах.

Comment: скорее всего, в initrd нет требующегося вам кода. но вы, конечно, можете уточнить, просмотрев его, начиная со скрипта init, который, вероятно, должен быть в корне initrd-образа.

Comment: в initrd есть нужный код. http://forum.altlinux.org/index.php/topic,34690.0.html

Comment: и что, получилось загрузиться из образа?

Comment: да. Но в ответе на этот вопрос на stackoverflow мне бы хотелось увидеть ссылки на документацию

Comment: так напишите ответ сами — это не запрещено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
menuentry "AltLinux 7.0.5, simply install" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    insmod xfs
    set bootpart=uuid:df46d821-e7f9-4e35-bbd2-728bdce8d89a
    set isodir=/iso/Alt705simple
    set isofile=altlinux-7.0.5-simply-x86_64-install-dvd5.iso
    loopback loop (${root})${isodir}/${isofile}
    linux (loop)/syslinux/alt0/vmlinuz automatic=method:disk,${bootpart},directory:${isodir}/${isofile} ramdisk_size=183210 changedisk lang=ru_RU splash noeject xdriver=auto quiet=1 showopts
    initrd (loop)/syslinux/alt0/full.cz
}
```

Comment: вот бы «оно» ещё умело брать iso-образ не с *hdd*, а с *cd/dvd*… меня именно такая возможность интересует: глядишь, *altlinux* чаще бы попадал на диски, идущие с *linuxformat*-ом. а то нынче невозможность запуска прямо с *dvd* значительно уменьшает вероятность такого «попадания».

Comment: я думаю, что версию "live" можно запустить прямо с DVD. Вам следует либо создать отдельный вопрос, либо выяснить всё самостоятельно

Comment: мой комментарий был не вопросом, а, скажем так, сетованием на «несовершенство мира»: насколько я смог разобраться в исходниках *propagator*-а, эта возможность (запуск из *iso*, записанного в виде файла на *cd/dvd*) там просто не реализована.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ещё б это сетование было высказано хотя бы в community@, а не где-то в интернетах... в принципе можно подумать над чем-то таким для стартеркитов, если http://altlinux.org/propagator ещё такого не умеет через какой-нить параметр

Comment: @MichaelShigorin, да вроде бы где-то уже комментировал по этому поводу, и, насколько помню, skull что-то отвечал (не помню точно что, но, вроде бы, неутешительное).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну а что он ответит с его перегрузом-то?  вот FR на propagator был бы хоть с шансами на исправление: https://bugzilla.altlinux.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Sisyphus :)

Comment: @MichaelShigorin https://bugzilla.altlinux.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32845

Comment: спасибо, толково!

Answer (score 1):

Пример моего 40_custom

```js
menuentry "AltLinux 7.0.5, simply install" {
 insmod loopback
 set gfxpayload=keep
 insmod gzio
 insmod part_msdos
 insmod ext2
 insmod xfs
 set bootpart=uuid:603ef866-453a-4c27-9799-3f03e6c167de
 set isodir=/iso
 set isofile=altlinux-7.0.5-simply-x86_64-install-dvd5.iso
 loopback loop (${root})${isodir}/${isofile}
 linux (loop)/syslinux/alt0/vmlinuz automatic=method:disk,${bootpart},directory:${isodir}/${isofile} ramdisk_size=183210 changedisk lang=ru_RU splash noeject xdriver=auto quiet=1 showopts
 initrd (loop)/syslinux/alt0/full.cz
}

menuentry "Alt Linux 7.0.5 Simply failsafe" {
 insmod loopback
 set gfxpayload=keep
 insmod gzio
 insmod part_msdos
 insmod ext2
 insmod xfs
 set bootpart=uuid:603ef866-453a-4c27-9799-3f03e6c167de
 set isodir=/iso
 set isofile=altlinux-7.0.5-simply-x86_64-install-dvd5.iso
 loopback loop (${root})${isodir}/${isofile}
 linux (loop)/syslinux/alt0/vmlinuz lowmem automatic=method:disk,${bootpart},directory:${isodir}/${isofile} ramdisk_size=183210 showopts noapic pci=nomsi acpi=off noload=ahci
 initrd (loop)/syslinux/alt0/full.cz
}

menuentry "Alt Linux 7.0.5 Simply LiveCD" {
 insmod loopback
 set gfxpayload=keep
 insmod gzio
 insmod part_msdos
 insmod ext2
 insmod xfs
 set bootpart=uuid:603ef866-453a-4c27-9799-3f03e6c167de
 set isodir=/iso
 set isofile=altlinux-7.0.5-simply-x86_64-install-dvd5.iso
 loopback loop (${root})${isodir}/${isofile}
 linux (loop)/syslinux/alt0/vmlinuz lowmem lang=ru_RU automatic=method:disk,${bootpart},directory:${isodir}/${isofile} fastboot splash=silent splashcount=17 stagename=live showopts noeject noprompt --
 initrd (loop)/syslinux/alt0/full.cz

}

menuentry "Alt Linux 7.0.5 Simply rescue" {
 insmod loopback
 set gfxpayload=keep
 insmod gzio
 insmod part_msdos
 insmod ext2
 insmod xfs
 set bootpart=uuid:603ef866-453a-4c27-9799-3f03e6c167de
 set isodir=/iso
 set isofile=altlinux-7.0.5-simply-x86_64-install-dvd5.iso
 loopback loop (${root})${isodir}/${isofile}
 linux (loop)/syslinux/alt0/vmlinuz lowmem automatic=method:disk,${bootpart},directory:${isodir}/${isofile} ramdisk_size=183210 fastboot stagename=rescue showopts
 initrd (loop)/syslinux/alt0/full.cz
}
```

Образ лежит в отдельном разделе /boot (ext2/3/4) UUID которого указан в скрипте, в папке /iso. Подставьте свои значения и будет вам щастие. Единственный момент - в режиме Live CD у меня не работала ВаФля.